# I want create a network chart using D3js and API everything is working fine but I failed to create code that show connection between circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a network chart where I can show Circle connecting another circle.

I have two API fetching two different data from different database table.

In 'api/chartdata' it has data like id, role_name and parent_circle (which contains foreign key of another table called circle) and in 'api/circle' it has circle_id,name i want to Target circle_id with the parent_circle so that it shows all the circle from the 'api/circle' and show connected circle by using parent_circle from 'api/chartdata'

Also I want to show name of the both circle and role by using data name and role_name but in my version of code it only showing circle name from 'api/circle'

Here's my version of d3js code that shows the circle

`

```
<script>


 // Fetch data from 'api/circle' and 'api/chartdata'


 Promise.all([


        d3.json('api/circle'),


        d3.json('api/chartdata')


    ]).then(([circleData, chartData]) => {


        // Transform the data into a suitable format


        const nodes = [


            { nodeId: 'general', name: 'General', type: 'general' }, // Default "General" circle


            ...circleData.map(circle => ({ nodeId: `circle_${circle.id}`, name: circle.name, type: 'circle' })),


            ...chartData.map(data => ({ nodeId: `chart_${data.role_name}`, name: data.role_name, type: 'chart' }))


        ];





        const links = [


            ...chartData.map(data => ({ source: `chart_${data.role_name}`, target: `chart_${data.role_name}` })), // Connect chart nodes


            ...circleData.map(circle => ({ source: 'general', target: `circle_${circle.id}` })), // Connect "General" to circles


            ...chartData.map(data => ({ source: 'general', target: `chart_${data.role_name}` })) // Connect "General" to chart nodes


        ];





        // Create the D3 force simulation


        const width = 700;


        const height = 600;


        


        const svg = d3.select('#chart')


            .append('svg')


            .attr('width', width)


            .attr('height', height);





            const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)


            .force('link', d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.nodeId))


            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))


            .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));





        const link = svg.selectAll('.link')


            .data(links)


            .enter().append('line')


            .attr('class', 'link');





        const node = svg.selectAll('.node')


            .data(nodes)


            .enter().append('circle')


            .attr('class', 'node')


            .attr('r', d => (d.type === 'circle' ? 45 : 35))


            .attr('fill', d => {


                if (d.type === 'circle') return 'yellow';


                if (d.type === 'chart') return 'orange';


                return 'gray'; // Default color for "General"


            });





        const label = svg.selectAll('.label')


            .data(nodes)


            .enter().append('text')


            .attr('class', 'label')    


            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')


            .attr('dy', 10)


            .text(d => {


                if (d.type === 'circle') return d.name;


                if (d.type === 'chart') return d.role_name;


                


            });





        simulation.on('tick', () => {


            link


                .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)


                .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)


                .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)


                .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);





            node


                .attr('cx', d => d.x)


                .attr('cy', d => d.y);





            label


                .attr('x', d => d.x)


                .attr('y', d => d.y);


        });


    }).catch(error => {


        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);


    });


</script>
```

`

In provided code the circle from both data are showing but only connection and name isn't showing